# How to pass Encoder as parameter to dataframe's as method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

I want to convert dataFrame to dataSet by using different case class.
Now, my code is like below.

```
case Class Views(views: Double)
case Class Clicks(clicks: Double)

def convertViewsDFtoDS(df: DataFrame){
    df.as[Views]
}

def convertClicksDFtoDS(df: DataFrame){
    df.as[Clicks]
}
```

So, my question is "Is there anyway I can use one general function to this by pass case class as extra parameter to this function?"

Answer (score 4):

It seems a bit obsolete (`as` method does exactly what you want) but you can

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Dataset, DataFrame}

def convertTo[T : Encoder](df: DataFrame): Dataset[T] = df.as[T]
```

or

```
def convertTo[T](df: DataFrame)(implicit enc: Encoder[T]): Dataset[T] = df.as[T]
```

Both methods are equivalent and express exactly the same thing (existence of an implicit `Encoder` for a type `T`).

If you want to avoid implicit parameter you can use explicit `Encoder` all the way down:

```
def convertTo[T](df: DataFrame, enc: Encoder[T]): Dataset[T] = df.as[T](enc)

convertTo(df, encoderFor[Clicks])
```